# ggplot2: Display shift in stacked histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to replicate a figure used in Stroke research to display results of clinical trials.
I have included a figure down below as an example of the end result.

In a nutshell, the figure is a stacked histogram in percentage for two conditions (such as drug vs placebo).
To indicate the shift, line are drawn from one bar to the next to emphasize the effect of treatment.
**Image:**
[Image from published paper here https://doi.org/10.3389/fneur.2022.973095](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OluMX.jpg)

The data will be something like:

```
mRS      Drug1      Drug2
0         10%        8%
1         12%        10%
2         22%        18%
3         9%         14%
4         15%        16%
5         12%        12%
6         20%        22%
```

Creating an horizontal stacked histogram is relatively simple, but I have no clue on how to create the line between the horizontal bars.
Any helps or just hint toward an appropriate method to do so would be much appreciated!
Thanks,

I tried to look on google for images of "horizontal stacked histogram" and apparently no one published something like that ;-)

Comment: That is indeed a duplicate question thank you for pointing that out - I had not found it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very similar approach to stefan here, but trying to match the original aesthetic more closely:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Drug1:Drug2, ~ as.numeric(sub('%', '', .x))/100)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-mRS, names_to = 'Drug', values_to = 'percent') %>%
  mutate(mRS = factor(mRS), y = as.numeric(factor(Drug))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(percent, y, fill = mRS)) +
  geom_segment(data = . %>% select(-y) %>% 
                 pivot_wider(names_from = 'Drug', values_from = 'percent') %>%
                 mutate(across(Drug1:Drug2, cumsum)),
               aes(y = 1.2, yend = 1.8, x = Drug1, xend = Drug2),
               alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_col(orientation = 'y', position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE),
           width = 0.4, col = 'gray60', linewidth = 0.2) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% 
              group_by(Drug) %>% 
              mutate(value = cumsum(percent),
                     stackval = lag(value, default = 0) + 0.5 * percent),
            aes(x = stackval, label = scales::percent(percent))) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Blues') +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = 1:2, labels = c('Drug 1', 'Drug 2'),
                     expand = c(0.3, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = 'gray50'),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a perfectionist when it comes to styling. :D

Comment: Thanks Allan, That is really something very helpful!
Side note in the geom_col: the parameter linewidth is unknown.
I assumed you meant size = 0.2 is that correct?

Comment: @user1139139 yes, `size` has been deprecated in favour of `linewidth` in the latest version of ggplot, so you may wish to update?

Answer (score 2):

Besides some data wrangling and cleaning drawing the connecting lines requires setting the start and end positions right.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

width <- .6

dat <- dat |>
  pivot_longer(-mRS) |>
  mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value) / 100) |>
  mutate(
    name_num = as.numeric(factor(name)),
    nudge_y = width / 2 * if_else(name_num == 1, 1, -1)
  )

ggplot(dat, aes(value, name, fill = factor(mRS))) +
  geom_col(aes(color = factor(mRS)), width = width, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = name_num + nudge_y, group = mRS), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), orientation = "y") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value, accuracy = 1)), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = .5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), guide = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, color = NULL)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(mRS = 0:6, Drug1 = c(
  "10%", "12%", "22%", "9%",
  "15%", "12%", "20%"
), Drug2 = c(
  "8%", "10%", "18%", "14%", "16%",
  "12%", "22%"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks stefan very helpful!
And the "simpler" version in terms of aesthetics means it is easier to read ;-)